# Как правильно разместить скрипт google analitycs на определенной странице в Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

На конкретной странице нужен код Google Analitycs.

Сразу просится логичное решение поместить его в

```
<head>...</head>
```

в header.php:

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'needle_page_url')) : ?>
    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    ........
    </script>
<?php endif?>
```

Как по мне, так выглядит костылём.

Или есть другие способы реализовать это в Битрикс?

Comment: В битриксе <head> находится в шаблонной части, которая едина для всех страниц сайта. Если Вам надо на одной конкретной стнанице, значит, вставляйте непосредственно в тело этой страницы

Comment: Это страница товара, она формируется  динамически.

Comment: Вам надо повесить скрипт на вывод одного конкретного товара? Решение может быть таким: вывод товаров (как и любых других элементов инфоблоков битрикса) определяется шаблоном - зная id товара, на который Вам надо повесить скрипт, заходите в редактирование шаблона и в коде проверяете: if $arItem['ID'] == elementID { здесь гугл }

Comment: Можно и средствами js сделать: хотя страница формируется динамически, но url у неё вполне определённый - что-то типа /allgoods.php?ID=elementID; пишете в шаблоне if (window.location.href == url) { здесь гугл }

Comment: повесьте в шаблон компонента которые выводит детальную карточку товара catalog.element. Если правильно помню, то вам нужно прописать строку AddHeadScript в нужном шаблоне и тогда Ваш скрипт подключится на нужной странице и будет подключаться на всех страницах, где информацию выводит этот компонент.

Comment: @humster_spb "зная id товара, на который Вам надо повесить скрипт..." именно так и сделал :)